# Java Spring Specification nested join conditions

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jpql, criteria-api

I am trying to fetch a list of entities along with its relations based on a value of a field which is at the deepest level. The native SQL query itself seems simple enough but I am unable to do the filtering using JPQL or specifications.
The structures of my tables is `Ad -> SubmittedValue -> Configuration`, I want to be able to filter by the field which is inside the `Configuration` entity called `isSpecial`.
I currently have:

```
@Entity
public class Ad extends BaseEntity{
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ad")
    private List<SubmittedValue> values;
}

@Entity
/* @ToString and @EqualAndHashCode exclude "ad" */
public class SubmittedValue extends BaseEntity{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ad_id")
    private Ad ad;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "configuration_id")
    private Configuration configuration;
    }

@Entity
public class Configuration extends BaseEntity{
    private Boolean isSpecial = false;
}
```

I have so far tried using JPQL:

```
@Query("select a from Ad a inner join a.values as v inner join v.configuration as c on c.isSpecial = true where a.user.id =?1")
Page<Ad> findAllBySpecialConfiguration(Pageable page, Long userId);
```

And a speficiation which is written below. They are both returning the entity correctly but the exclusion of `SubmittedValues` in which the `isSpecial` value of `configuration` is `false` is not being applied to the results.
Here is my specification:

```
public static Specification<Ad> adSpecial(Long userId) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
      ListJoin<Ad, SubmittedValue> values = root.join(Ad_.values);
      Join<SubmittedValue, Configuration> config = values.join(SubmittedValue_.configuration);
      // config.on(criteriaBuilder.isTrue(config.get(Configuration_.isSpecial).as(Boolean.class)));
      List<Predicate> conditions = new ArrayList<>();
      conditions.add(criteriaBuilder.isTrue(config.get(Configuration_.isSpecial).as(Boolean.class)));
      conditions.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Ad_.user).get(User_.id).as(Long.class), userId));
      return criteriaBuilder.and(conditions.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    };
  }
```

Thanks and Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your line in specification

```
ListJoin<Ad, SubmittedValue> values = root.join(Ad_.values);
```

to

```
ListJoin<Ad, SubmittedValue> values = root.joinList(Ad_.values);
```

You can make your specification more dynamic by taking **isSpecial** as parameter value like this

```
public static Specification<Ad> adSpecial(Long userId, Boolean isSpecial) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        ListJoin<Ad, SubmittedValue> values = root.joinList("values");

        List<Predicate> conditions = new ArrayList<>();
        conditions.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(values.get("configuration").get("isSpecial"), isSpecial));
        conditions.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("user").get("id"), userId));

        return criteriaBuilder.and(conditions.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    };
}
```

Comment: Even after changing ```root.join``` to ```root.joinList``` I am still getting the same wrong results :(

Comment: Yes, I have also logged the generated SQL query: 
`select ad0_.id as id1_0_, ad0_.user_id as user_id15_0_ from ad ad0_ inner join submitted_values values1_ on ad0_.id=values1_.ad_id cross join configurations configurat2_ where values1_.configuration_id=configurat2_.id and configurat2_.is_special=? and ad0_.user_id=1`
Executing this query only returns Ad id and User id, later on there are multiple queries on the submitted_value table all of which include `configuration_id` comparisons(join condition) but not the `is_special` condition we added in the specification, maybe this is the issue?